# Run command in the background/menu bar

Tags: macos, command-line

Instead of running a command in terminal, is it possible to run it 'in' the menubar in the background?

To keep the firewall open within the network I am in I use `curl` to ping a url every 5 minutes, using [`watch`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watch_(Unix)) in Terminal, but this means I need to leave Terminal open all the time. Is it possible to 'send' this to the menu bar?

Comment: What about a cronjob or a cronjob that executes your scripts within a shell script?

Answer (score 3):

Not easily. To create a *menulet* - I presume this is what you mean by running it in the menu bar - you would need to write [some code of your own](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.22/22.02/Menulet/). Depending on your programming ability, and how much effort you want to put in, that may or may not be a solution.

Alternatively, you could minimise your terminal window to the dock. Depending on how visible you want the output to be, you could also run the command in the background with [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or otherwise. If you're looking for an obvious change, you could use a script that recognised this and used something like [growlnotify](http://growl.info/extras.php) to tell you about it.

Comment: Cheers. I was hoping there was a simple way to do it with Automator or something like that. I think screen would be the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Not the answer to your question, but probably to your problem:

Use `screen`. This way you can quit Terminal and your processes keep running.

`Ctrl-A Ctrl-C` (create) creates new "screens" ("tabs"/"windows"), `Ctrl-A Crtl-N` (next) and `Ctrl-A Ctrl-P` (previous) cycle through them. `Ctrl-A Ctrl-D` (detach) exits screen.

`screen -r` to re-attach to a previous screen session and check the output.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you need it in the menubar?

The following is a script that will loop, and hit some curl url on the loop.  You need to run it in the terminal, but can close the terminal after that.

```
#!/bin/bash

URL=http://some.site/
LOOPTIME=280 # just under 5 minutes

(while true;
do curl -I -s -o /dev/null $URL > /dev/null;
done) &
disown
```

I included -I to just use HEAD, to save both yours and the server's bandwidth